# get data-attribute value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two categories "1 & 2". My sample code are given below. I don't know how can I get values means categories in jQuery. Please help me to get values in "getData:"

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <section>
                    <div class="tag-handler-category" data-category="1">#KEYSKILLS</div><br>
                    <ul class="tag-handler">
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <section>
                    <div class="tag-handler-category" data-category="2">#INTERESTS</div><br>
                    <ul class="tag-handler">
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".tag-handler").tagHandler({
      getData: { tagcategoryid: $(".tag-handler-category").data('category') },
      getURL: '/tag/interest',
      autocomplete: true,
      autoUpdate: true
  });

</script>
```

Comment: What is `tagHandler()`?

Comment: @D4V1D, It's for generating data as tags.

Comment: Many answers on this website for getting the custom data-* attribute. I recommend you do some research before creating duplicate questions. Also: You don't have an attribute `getData`

Comment: @NewToJS, Currently tagcategoryid 1 is passing not passing 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you should change to this:

```
getData: { tagcategoryid: $(this).siblings(".tag-handler-category").data('category') },
```

As class selectors in js/jquery returns a collection, so you need to have a context for each element in the collection with keyword `this` and as the target element is at same level and its is a sibling of selector so you can use `.siblings()` method to get the target element.

---

Update: you can use `.each()` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".tag-handler").each(function(i, v){
      $(this).tagHandler({
          getData: { tagcategoryid: $(v).data('category') },
          getURL: '/tag/interest',
          autocomplete: true,
          autoUpdate: true
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: I have used your code but passing one category id. See firebug console result.                                                                                         GET http://www.ct.dev/tag/interest?tagcategoryid=1&_=1441275241152
 
GET http://www.ct.dev/tag/interest?tagcategoryid=1&_=1441275241153

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch category number associated with current section. In that case get `data()` as follows:

```
$(this).closest("section").find(".tag-handler-category").data('category')
```